# Why am I getting this error: Attempted import error: DatePickerField is not exported from /..whatever

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, material-ui, jsx, formik

I am trying to implement Formik fields in my material-ui form.  I ahve everything working except the date. What a nightmare.  I've had numerous issues, but the current one is React is telling me:

Attempted import error: DatePickerField is not exported from '../formfields'

Here's the DatePickerField.jsx file in full:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

const DatePickerField = props => {
  const [field, meta, helper] = useField(props);
  const { touched, error } = meta;
  const { setValue } = helper;
  const isError = touched && error && true;
  const { value } = field;
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      const date = new Date(value);
      setSelectedDate(date);
    }
  }, [value]);

  function _onChange(date) {
    if (date) {
      setSelectedDate(date);
      try {
        const ISODateString = date.toISOString();
        setValue(ISODateString);
      } catch (error) {
        setValue(date);
      }
    } else {
      setValue(date);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          {...field}
          {...props}
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={_onChange}
          error={isError}
          invalidDateMessage={isError && error}
          helperText={isError && error}
          disableToolbar
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default DatePickerField;
```

As you can see I'm exporting it fine.  But when I try to import it into my form I get the above error.  I've tried both:

```
import { DatePickerField } from '../../forms/formfields';
```

And:

```
import DatePickerField from '../../forms/formfields';
```

But I get the error either way.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: you gotta import from `../../forms/formfields/DatePickerField`.. no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not importing the file. you put the path, but didn't add the file you wanted from the formsfields folder..
So append /DatePickerField to the import path

Comment: Ah yes. I was using an index.js file to group all the field imports together.  Forget to change *that* file!  Thanks!